# Django DRF and XLSX binary file uploads from Postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi im trying to upload an XLSX to my django application with DRF. I am getting the follow error

```
{
    "detail": "Unsupported media type \"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\" in request."
}
```

My Header Content-Type is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet". The Django DRF document tells me DRF is passing me that error when i try to print(request.FILES), but it doesn't really explain how to handle this. Can someone show me how to handle XLSX file uploads? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't Django DRF, but rather my request item was in the body instead of the header.

Comment: make sure you are doing multi-form when making a request. then you can receive the XLSX as a binary in request.FILES